# Get variable value from html in typescript ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm writing a code but I can't get a value of a range from html page. I'm working on this(I want to set the brightness of a device) :

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-range [(ngModel)]="BrightnessValue" color="dark" pin="true" step="1" min="0" max="10">
      <ion-icon range-left small name="sunny"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon range-right name="sunny"></ion-icon>
    </ion-range>
  </ion-item>
```

In my ts :

```
......
  BrightnessValue: number ;
....
constructor(....){
console.log(this.BrightnessValue);
    Brightness.setBrightness(this.BrightnessValue);
}
```

But the value is always undefinde. So how can I send from html -> ts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is undefined because it was not initialized and you're trying to get that value from the constructor. Try by using the `ionChange` event:

```
 <ion-item>
    <ion-range (ionChange)="changeBrightness()" [(ngModel)]="BrightnessValue" color="dark" pin="true" step="1" min="0" max="10">
      <ion-icon range-left small name="sunny"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon range-right name="sunny"></ion-icon>
    </ion-range>
  </ion-item>
```

And in your code:

```
public changeBrightness(): void {
  console.log(this.BrightnessValue);
  Brightness.setBrightness(this.BrightnessValue);
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :)